# Android 14 foreground notification not updating

Tags: java, android

I recently updated my app's SDK to version 34 and encountered a problem when testing on Android 14. The foreground notification layout doesn't update properly unless I set the channel priority to high, but this introduces an unwanted popup.Code Snippet: Here's the relevant code from my implementation:

```
private void setup() {
    setupIndicatorIconGenerator();
    String channel = createChannel();
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, channel)
                    .setSmallIcon(getIndicatorIcon("", ""))
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setContent(mNotificationContentView)
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setSound(null)
                    .setVibrate(new long[] {0})
                    .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                    .setShowWhen(false)
                    .setLocalOnly(true);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        builder.setForegroundServiceBehavior(NotificationCompat.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_IMMEDIATE);
    }

    mNotificationBuilder = builder;
}

private synchronized String createChannel() {
    if (mContext == null) {
        // Handle the case where mContext is null
        return null;
    }

    this.mNotificationManager =  mContext.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);

    if (mNotificationManager == null) {
        // Handle the case where mNotificationManager is null
        return null;
    }

    String channelId = "id_channel";
    String channelName = "name";
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26){
    NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, importance);

    mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0});
    mChannel.enableVibration(false);
    mChannel.setSound(null, null);
    mChannel.setDescription("Description ");
            mChannel.setBypassDnd(true);
    mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }else{
            
            channelId = "";
        }
        return channelId;
}
```

The notification layout fails to update properly when the channel priority is not set to high. However, setting it to high introduces an unwanted popup.

**Attempts to Fix**: I've tried adjusting the channel priority and experimenting with foreground service behaviors, but I haven't found a satisfactory solution

[Link to Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7wQt.jpg)

Environment:SDK Version: 34
Android Version: 14

I expect the notification layout to update correctly without introducing a popup when the channel priority is set to a level other than high.